# Panasonic Camera Streaming MJPEG Video with G.726 Audio

Tags: c++, ip-camera

I'm finding out panasonic camera. I want to get audio data from this and try to play it. I sent a command to camera and receiced a stream data as following:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=--myboundary
--myboundary
Content-type: audio/g726
...binary data...
```

I have searched some open sources on internet to decode the stream data but actually i don't know the data encoded by this camera using u/a/l law, 2/3/4 bits, rigt/left packed these parameter neccessary to decode exactly. Does anyone know please tell me? Is there any format for g726?

Assume that I decoded successfully. Could you give me a piece of code written by C/C++ how to play the data after decoding. I mean that I want to hear the audio data which get from camera on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

ITU makes available source code for the [G.726](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.726/en) codec [here](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.191/en), though giving you code to do placyback seems a bit out of scope for an answer, and we'd have to at least know your operatating system..

Comment: Thanks for your info, these documents is so detailed but they aren't what i really need now. I'm using Window7.